# Jquery Return NaN

Tags: jquery, asp.net, nan

I am having some trouble with jQuery it returns always NaN

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=txttotalprice]").val("0");
});
$("body").on("change keyup", "[id*=txttotalprice]", function () {



    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("[id*=txttotalprice]").each(function () {
        grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
});
```

Comment: Try `grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).val());`

Comment: It's easier if u search your input with `$(#txttotalprice)`. Second, you should get your value by $(this).val() and when you want to change it, again use `$(this).val(grandTotal)`

Comment: @Serlok It's not equal to `#txttotalprice`, it means that `id` contains `txttotalprice` (e.g. `txttotalprice_1`) take a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)